# Is the new Power Gig guitar also compatible with Rock Band 3?

Tags: rock-band-3

As the title suggests, I want to know if [this](http://www.engadget.com/2010/10/23/power-gigs-full-size-handmade-guitar-controller-now-on-sale/) is going to work with Rock Band 3's new Pro mode.  I really only want to have to buy one 300 dollar peripheral this year, if at all possible.

Comment: I think you're aiming for the Pro mode, rather than the regular 5 button mode. Perhaps wise to emphasize if so ;-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, it is standard 5 button gameplay compatible.

However, it will *not* work for Rock Band 3 pro guitar mode.

More detail:

> It doesn't support RB3's pro mode. The way it works in Power Gig is that the first five frets are the equivalent of the five buttons when you use it as a game controller, and then frets 7-11 act as solo buttons.
>
> The result is that the sound the guitar makes when you strum doesn't sound anything like the song you're playing. Apparently you need a rubber muter for the strings too, or the game will read the continued vibration of the strings as you constantly strumming. The guitar works as a real guitar, but when you're using it as a controller, it's regular five-button gameplay.